# Get Date difference and add to new date php

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I have two dates and i want to get the difference.I can strtotime like this

```
$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$seconds_diff = $ts2 - $ts1;
```

I want to add the result to today date.like if i get result 1 year and 20 days .My new date will be next year and 20 days.How can i add the result to new date.Thanks My issue is not difference but how to add that to new date.

Comment: Have a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

You must use date_diff and date_add function:
`$result = date_add(new DateTime(), date_diff($ts2-$ts1))`